# TranslateAnimation with %p not working in in samsung S3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

Hi guys i am doing translate animation where i need to move my view( which is at the center of the screen ,but not exactly ) upward so that it can fit to the container placed 9dp from top.I have figured it out that if i translate view from 0%p to 52%p it will exactly fit the in the container layout for XHDPI devices.which worked perfect on google galaxy nexus device ( 720 X 1280 ) but the same thing is not working on samsung s3.In S3 i need to move the view onlty 50%p.Please tell me how can i resolve this devices dependent issue?And Why this happens?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different animation values for different screens.For example you can put the same xml file for the animation in values-xhdpi and switch some values.This way all xhdpi devices will load this animation all other devices will load the default animation.

Comment: Hey my issue is different.nexus and s3 both are XHDPI devices but the toDeltaY value in %p is working for nexus but not for S3

Comment: Oh yes, there was some problem with the translate animation in android 4.1. if the s3 is running that version of android you cant use translate animation.

Comment: yes i tested this scenario on s3 running 4.1.2 .do you mean its buggy and we can't solve this issue?

Comment: You can solve this issue but with custom code.I remember when tested something with translate animation on my first upgrade on nexus 7. It wasn't working.I've made some research and found that other people found that problem too.A few weeks after that google have updated the android and it was working again.So I think that is platform specific problem and you can't do much about it.You can always write those animations by your self or take the code from the previous versions but Im not sure if its worth the effort :)

Comment: Some suggestions are like calculate device's ydpi value then convert it into some percentage like 1 dp = ydpi vaule / 100 ( to find out % ) and then see if top conatiner is 9 dp so howmuch % we need to reduce.blah blah blah............do u think it worth doing that?

Comment: Try to figure what is not working in the source code.And mb fix it.I've done this so many times :) http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/

Comment: Hey Could you please give me few links that address this 4.1 versions issue for TranslateAnimations so that i can also let my client to know about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is issue is resolved.I don't know whether these issues can be particular version specific or else ,but i just tried the code with starting Animations pragmatically instead using anim xml files.I used animations this way and it worked  like a charm.

```
 slide_up = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.ABSOLUTE, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, -610);
```